# convert str time to kml timeStamp in java

Tags: java, timestamp, kml

i building a kml file and there is a line of timestamp:

```
<gx:TimeStamp>
          <when>2002-07-09T19:00:00-08:00</when>
        </gx:TimeStamp>
```

i need convert time like: "1430477311" to "2002-07-09T19:00:00-08:00" format

how ?
(java code)
tnx a lot

Answer (score 2):

You are wanting to convert from your timeformat to XML Date Format (ISO-8601) -

```
long timeStamp = 1430477311L;
java.util.Date yourDate = new java.util.Date(timeStamp*1000); //ms
SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMddTHHmmssSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
String date = yyyyMMddTHHmmssSDF.format(yourDate);
```

[Simple Date Format reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Date Format (ISO-8601) is UTC time zone so must set time zone in the SimpleDateFormat instance to that. Otherwise you get the local time.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the timestamp to a `Date` type:

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(inputTimestamp);
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
//change the to the format that you need
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String timeStr = df.format(date);
```